# SQL Query to get the json array values by comma separated

Tags: sql, json, sql-server-2019

I have the below Json object. I need to get the task names by comma (,) separated.

```
{
  "Model": [
    {
      "ModelName": "Test Model",    
      "Object": [
         {
           "ID": 1,
           "Name": "ABC",
           "Task" : [
             {
                TaskID : 1222,
                Name: "TaskA"
             },
             {
                TaskID : 154,
                Name: "TaskB"
             }
           ]
         },
         {
           "ID": 11,
           "Name": "ABCD",
           "Task" : [
             {
                TaskID : 222,
                Name: "TaskX"
             },
             {
               TaskID : 234,
               Name: "TaskY"
             }
           ]
        },         
     ]  
 }]}
```

The expected Output should be in the below table. I need the task names should be comma separated.

```
ModelName   ObjectID   ObjectName  TaskName
Test Model     1          ABC      TaskA, TaskB
Test Model     11         ABCD     TaskX, TaskY
```

I tried the below query. But I don't know how to group Task names.

```
                  SELECT   S1.ModelName,
                           S2.ID  AS ObjectID, 
                           S2.Name AS ObjectName, 
                           S3.TaskName
                     FROM TableA 
                       CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(JsonData)
                         WITH (Model NVARCHAR(MAX) '$.Model[0]' AS JSON) S1
                       CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (S1.Model) 
                         WITH (Object NVARCHAR(MAX) '$.Object' AS JSON,
                               ID  INT '$.ID',
                               Name NVARCHAR(250) '$.Name') S2
                       CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (S2.Object) 
                         WITH (Task NVARCHAR(MAX) '$.Task' AS JSON ,
                               TaskName NVARCHAR(MAX) '$.TaskName') S3
```

Comment: how do you get the above JSON object.

Comment: Do not store values as csv. Redesign your database

Comment: @isuru I get the Json object from the model. I store into the table column. I just need to write q query to that Json Column.

Comment: @Jens It was not a .csv. It was a JSON object. SQL Server 2019 supports that.

Comment: @AshokYaganti `'TaskA, TaskB'` are comma separated values...If you  are extracting the JSON data, normalise it too. What have you tried so far, and why didn't it work?

Comment: @Larnu I can able to select ModelName, ObjectID, ObjectName using Cross Apply. Even I can display the TaskName. But I need to group task names by comma separated.

Comment: [edit] your question, @AshokYaganti , show your attempt there.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan do you have any idea about this?

Comment: @Larnu I tried the above query but I need the group of tasknames.

Answer (score 0):

Corrected the json to a valid format and here is the SQL query for your desired output. The below query compiles and runs well in [Oracle Compiler](https://rextester.com/l/oracle_online_compiler)

```
SELECT * FROM JSON_TABLE(
    '{"Model":[{"ModelName":"Test Model","Object":[{"ID":1,"Name":"ABC","Task":[{"TaskID":1222,"Name":"TaskA"},{"TaskID":154,"Name":"TaskB"}]},{"ID":11,"Name":"ABCD","Task":[{"TaskID":222,"Name":"TaskX"},{"TaskID":234,"Name":"TaskY"}]}]}]}',
    '$.Model[*]'
    COLUMNS (
       -- L_MODEL_ROWNUM FOR ORDINALITY,
        L_MODEL_NAME VARCHAR2(10) PATH '$.ModelName',
        NESTED PATH '$.Object[*]' COLUMNS (
            --L_OBJECT_ROWNUM FOR ORDINALITY,
            L_OBJECT_ID NUMBER PATH '$.ID',
            L_OBJECT_NAME VARCHAR2(10) PATH '$.Name',
            L_TASK_NAME VARCHAR2(100) FORMAT JSON WITH WRAPPER PATH '$.Task[*].Name'
            )
        )
    )
```

Here is the query which runs on **SQL Server 2019**,

```
DECLARE @JSONDATA NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET
   @JSONDATA = N'{"Model":[{"ModelName":"Test Model","Object":[{"ID":1,"Name":"ABC","Task":[{"TaskID":1222,"Name":"TaskA"},{"TaskID":154,"Name":"TaskB"}]},{"ID":11,"Name":"ABCD","Task":[{"TaskID":222,"Name":"TaskX"},{"TaskID":234,"Name":"TaskY"}]}]}]}';
WITH TASK AS 
(
   SELECT
      MODEL,
      ID,
      NAME,
      TASK_NAME 
   FROM
      OPENJSON(@JSONDATA) WITH (MODELS NVARCHAR(MAX) '$.Model' AS JSON)
      CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(MODELS) WITH (MODEL NVARCHAR(80) '$.ModelName', OBJECTS NVARCHAR(MAX) '$.Object' AS JSON) 
      CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(OBJECTS ) WITH (ID INT '$.ID', NAME NVARCHAR(250) '$.Name', TASKS NVARCHAR(MAX) '$.Task' AS JSON ) 
      CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (TASKS) WITH (TASK_NAME NVARCHAR(80) '$.Name') 
)
SELECT DISTINCT
   MODEL AS MODELNAME,
   ID AS OBJECTID,
   NAME AS OBJECTNAME,
   STUFF(( 
   SELECT
      ',' + [TASK_NAME] 
   FROM
      TASK T1 
   WHERE
      T1.[ID] = T2.[ID] FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS TASKNAME 
   FROM
      TASK T2;
```

Comment: This isn't valid T-SQL.`varchar2` isn't even a valid datatype in SQL Server. Oracle, also, is a *completely* different RDBMS.

Comment: @AshokYaganti Added the SQL server query to get the desired output